# Make a horizontal scroll menu in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, menu

I want to create a horizontal scrolling menu like Pinterest:

[image]

I don't want to use Bootstrap or react, I just want to use HTML, CSS and Javascript.

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp is a good place to start.

Comment: @King11 I tried to do it as the link you sent, but I don't know how to place the buttons to go left or right. Do you know how?

Comment: Do you have a code snippet or jsfiddle of your current code? I would need to see what you're working with to provide more help for you.

Comment: @King11 https://jsfiddle.net/Sain_MX/khro9ns2/

Comment: So you just want the arrows to click to go left or right?

Comment: @King11 Yes, just that

Comment: Ok, I will see what i can do

Comment: Do you only want to use javascript? Or would you like to add some jquery?

Comment: Only javascript, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created you a little example.

So basically you will create a container with a fixed width. This will be the displayed view. In that container you will create a new one that overflows out of the parent, however the parent container won't show the overflow.

If you then click left or right, you will slide your inner div to the left or right and show the other content.

```js
var btnL = document.getElementById("btnLeft");
var btnR = document.getElementById("btnRight");

var content = document.getElementById("content");

btnR.addEventListener("click", goRight);
btnL.addEventListener("click", goLeft);

var clickedIndex = 0;

function goRight()
{
 if (clickedIndex < 2)
  {
    clickedIndex = clickedIndex +1;
     content.style.marginLeft = -190*clickedIndex + "px";  
  }

}

function goLeft()
{
 if (clickedIndex >0)
  {
    clickedIndex = clickedIndex -1;
 content.style.marginLeft = -190*clickedIndex + "px";  
 
  }
}
```

```css
.mainViewer
{
  max-width:570px;
  width:570px;
  height:250px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.content 
{
  display: flex;
  height:100%;
  min-width:calc(190px *5);
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all .6s;
    
}

.card
{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.clickable
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainViewer">
  
  <div class="content" id="content">
  
    <div class="card">
     1
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
     2
    </div>

    <div class="card">
     3
    </div>

    <div class="card">
     4
    </div>

    <div class="card">
     5
    </div>

  </div>



</div>

<a class="clickable" id="btnLeft">Left</a>
<a class="clickable" id="btnRight">Right</a>
```

Comment: In your html code 5 cards appear, but when you run the code it only allows me to scroll to 4. How can I solve this?

Comment: @SebastiánVarellaGmz This is because I limited the js to scroll only one to the right and then disable the action. Just check the position and allow it to scroll multiple times

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @SebastiánVarellaGmz I have updated the example above for you. Just store in a int your current state and then allow it to click right or not.